# Executing a command from the current directory without dot slash like "./command"

Tags: bash, unix

I feel like I'm missing something very basic so apologies if this question is obtuse. I've been struggling with this problem for as long as I've been using the bash shell.

Say I have a structure like this:

```
├──bin
   ├──command (executable)
```

This will execute:

```
$ bin/command
```

then I symlink bin/command to the project root

```
$ ln -s bin/command c
```

like so

```
├──c (symlink to bin/command)
├──bin
   ├──command (executable)
```

I can't do the following (errors with `-bash: c: command not found`)

```
$ c
```

I must do?

```
$ ./c
```

**What's going on here?** — is it possible to execute a command from the current directory without preceding it with `./` and also without using a system wide alias? It would be very convenient for distributed executables and utility scripts to give them one letter folder specific shortcuts on a per project basis.

Comment: You could add `.` to your `PATH`... Also there is `~/.local/bin` for user specific binaries on many distros.

Comment: Cool, I tested that and it works… crazy simple.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not a matter of bash not allowing execution from the current directory, but rather, you haven't added the current directory to your list of directories to execute from.

```
export PATH=".:$PATH"

$ c
$
```

This can be a security risk, however, because if the directory contains files which you don't trust or know where they came from, a file existing in the currently directory could be confused with a system command.

For example, say the current directory is called "foo" and your colleague asks you to go into "foo" and set the permissions of "bar" to 755.  As root, you run "chmod foo 755"

You assume chmod really is chmod, but if there is a file named chmod in the current directory and your colleague put it there, chmod is really a program he wrote and you are running it as root.  Perhaps "chmod" resets the root password on the box or something else dangerous.

Therefore, the standard is to limit command executions which don't specify a directory to a set of explicitly trusted directories.

Comment: Thanks for detailing how an attack could be leveraged. In my case the risk is relatively low but I see why the convention exists, definitely gives me something to think about when fretting over a few keystrokes.

Comment: Please don't suggest to put `.` at the beginning of the PATH. That is an very poor practice and you give a good example about why. Putting `.` at the end of the PATH answers Mark's question is far less risky.

Answer (score 6):

### Beware that the accepted answer introduces a serious vulnerability!

---

You might add the current directory to your PATH but not at the beginning of it. That would be a very risky setting.

There are still possible vulnerabilities when the current directory is at the end but far less so this is what I would suggest:

```
PATH="$PATH":.
```

Here, the current directory is only searched **after** every directory already present in the PATH is explored so the risk to have an existing command overloaded by an hostile one is no more present. There is still a risk for an uninstalled command or a typo to be exploited, but it is much lower. Just make sure the dot is always at the end of the PATH when you add new directories in it.

Comment: To expand on the reason for putting it at the end of the PATH: it minimizes the risk of the attack @Brandon mentioned, because the PATH is searched in order. If ./chmod and /bin/chmod both exist, and /bin is before . in PATH, /bin/chmod will take precedence and the attack (at least this version) won't work. Also, if you add several things to PATH (e.g. in your ~/.bash_profile), make sure . gets added *last*, so it winds up after everything else you add.

Answer (score 1):

You could add `.` to your `PATH`. (See kamituel's answer for details)

Also there is `~/.local/bin` for user specific binaries on many distros.

Comment: Lately I've been using Composer which is a dependency manager for php that is a lot like npm in that it is often used for project specific resources so each projects dependancies (including binaries) are isolated from each other. Makes sense why executables are conventionally in `bin` I guess.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is add the current dir (`.`) to the `$PATH`:

```
export PATH=.:$PATH
```

But this can pose a security issue, so be aware of that. See [this ServerFault answer](https://serverfault.com/a/98595) on why it's not so good idea, especially for the root account.

Comment: If you do add it, please put it at the end. See @jlliagre's answer.